# According to the Calvinist, how to choose which one is the meaning when the word Thanatos ---VS--- Neukros appear in a sentence?

Tags: death

verse-A (Romans 5:12)

> Therefore, just as sin entered the world through one man, and death
>   through sin, and in this way death came to all people, because all
>   sinned

verse-B (Romans 5:10)

> For if, while we were God's enemies, we were reconciled to him through
>   the death of his Son, how much more, having been reconciled, shall we
>   be saved through his life!

The word [death] in the two verses above in Greek is [thanatos].

In verse-A, it seems many Christian interpretation of the word [death] there is a spiritual-dead condition.

But if I go consistent, then it sounds weird if [the death of his Son] means  spiritual-dead in verse-B. I think it's most likely means [physical-dead] in verse-B.

---

on the other hand :

verse-C (Matthew 28:7)

> And go quickly and tell His disciples that He is risen from the dead

verse-D (Ephesians 2:5)

> even though we were dead because of our sins

The word [dead] in the two verses above in Greek is [nekrous].

In verse-C, logically the word [dead] means physical-dead. But if I go consistent with this, then it sounds weird if [we were dead] means [we have been physically-dead] in verse-D. I think it's most likely means [spiritually-dead] in verse-D.

---

I've tried to think like this : 
the word [thanatos] in verse-A and the word [nekrous] in verse-C is about future time, which is [a second death, physically].

So, if there is no Jesus - the next generation will taste the second death at the end of times because all sinned. (verse-A).

If there is no Jesus, *we will taste the second death at the end of times because of our sins* (verse-D).

But of course is only logical not biblical :).
So, how is the correct way to understand a verse like those above according to the Calvinist ?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: This is probably better for hermeneutics.se

Comment: @jlaverde, I will wait for a few days if there is an answer here. If not I will move this question to hermeneutics.se as your suggestion. Thank you.